# IOS7 Custom TableViewCell will not appear

Tags: ios, uitableview, ios7, ios7.1

I am trying to create a project with a custom UITableViewCell. The custom cells never load, they're just blank. At this point in the project what I'm trying to do is placing a UITableViewCell in a .xib, designing it the way I want and specifying its reuse identifier along with tag IDs for the components so that I can use them in code later on.

I've googled a ton and found several tutorials that look like what I want to do, along with many SO questions that have answers that seem applicable. At this point it's probably just my head spinning with too many different angles and solutions.

This is my current attempt at trying to register the custom cell with my UITableView, yet when running this on a device the rows in the table view are entirely blank.

```
    UITableViewCell* cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"MyCell"];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"MyCell"];
}

UILabel* l1 = (UILabel*)[cell viewWithTag:1];
UILabel* l2 = (UILabel*)[cell viewWithTag:2];
UILabel* l3 = (UILabel*)[cell viewWithTag:3];

l1.text = @"Foobar";
l2.text = @"Foobar";
l3.text = @"Foobar";
```

I'm pretty certain that I've hooked up all the properties and such correctly, but at this stage I need a fresh pair of eyes to point out the facepalm for me.

The interesting files are FilmerView.m/h/xib and the cell is in FilmerViewCell.xib. When running the app this TableView is in the second tab of the tab bar controller.

**Project:**

http://speedy.sh/WhhpP/test12.zip

Comment: what is your custom cell name?where you are using?

Comment: your .zip file does not open

Comment: You should be using the method Fogmeister mentions in his answer, but you also should be returning an instance of your custom class in the dequeue method not a UITableViewCell. It's also unusual to use tags in a custom cell rather than creating outlets for each of your labels, and referring to them by name.

Comment: @rdelmar it is fine to return UITableViewCell in the datasource method as your custom class will be a subclass of it anyway so the tableview doesn't care. As long as it's derived from UITableViewCell.

Comment: @Fogmeister, sure, you will get whatever class the dequeue method returns, but if you type it as a UITableViewCell, you'll get an error if you try to access any properties of your class -- it's not clear whether Antevirus has any custom properties, but he should. It seems silly to use tags in this way if you have your own custom class.

Comment: Ah, I always use a method to configure the cell anyway. (See my answer). That way it makes it easier to work with NSFetchedResultsController and it's something I've stuck with.

Answer (score 1):

I can't provide a full answer atm but look up the tableview method. `registerNib:forCellReuseIdentifier:`

Also, stop using that dequeue method. Use the one that includes the indexPath.

Then you don't have to check if the cell is nil afterwards.

**EDIT**

In `viewDidLoad` (or somewhere like that)...

```
UINib *cellNib = [UINib nibWithNibName:@"MyCustomCellXibFileName" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
[self.tableView registerNib:cellNib forCellReuseIdentifier:@"CellIdentifier"];
```

Now in the table view datasource method...

```
- (UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"CellIdentifier" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    // no need to check cell == nil.
    // this method is guaranteed to return a non nil cell.
    // if it doesn't then the program will crash telling you that you need to...
    // register a class or nib (but we just did this in viewDidLoad) :D

    // configure your cell here...
    [self configureMyCell:(MyCustomCell *)cell atIndexPath:indexPath];

    return cell;
}

- (void)configureMyCell:(MyCustomCell *)cell atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    cell.nameLabel.text = @"Hello, world";
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I think I commented on this in another answer of yours, but it doesn't matter (with regards to having to use an if cel}l==nil clause) if you use the older dequeue method or the newer one with the indexPath parameter. If you make the cell in the storyboard, or register the nib, either method is guaranteed to return a cell. As far as I can tell, the only difference in use between these two methods is that the older method will return nil if it can't find the cell (wrong or missing identifier), whereas the newer method throws an exception.

Comment: @rdelmar exactly, the old method is there because tableview's didn't used to set up their own cells. Use the registerNib method and the new dequeue method. Then it's pointless to check for nil anyway. You can check if the cell is nil if you want to add some extra pointless code to your project. But it seems a bit daft.

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure that you have set datasource and delegate properties of your tableView.
2. Make sure that you have implemented `(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section` method and it returns a positive value (>0).

Answer (score -1):

Evaluate the following:

1. Is the ReuseIdentifier set in the XIB. See Properties Tab in Interface Builder on the right when selecting the cell.
2. Are the AutoresizingMasks set properly for the labels to be visible?
3. WrapModes: Which did you select? When having wrapmode WrapWord, is the font size too large for the text to be moved in the next line becoming invisible?
4. Set the background color of the UITableViewCellss content view to something else than white or transparent, as well as the background colors of the labels to see if the cell is even there.
5. Manually call numberOfRowsInSection on your table, pass the proper NSIndexPath identifying the target section and see if its greater 0 to confirm that the TableView even attempts to load the data, thus, the cells. ( Alternatively set a breakpoint in the method or do a NSLog. )
6. Do a NSLog in cellForRowAtIndexPath to confirm that the cell returned is not nil and the method is even called!